# Magento API with iOS application and Oauth 1.0 Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, magento, oauth

I want to use `magento API` in my application to get product list, add to 
cart and purchase it from application etc.

I am very new to magento, I want to know that do I need to implement `oauth 1.0` login to use API from my iOS application?

As per this link, I am assuming that I need to implement oauth 1.0 [Magento API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html)

I have tried with this sample code [Oauth 1.0](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/simple-oauth-1-0a-client), I am able to get `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier`.

But in last step I want `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` which I am not getting and instead of that I am getting html page in response. Not sure where I am wrong.

Can you please guide me am I going on right track to use magento API
And to use **Oauth 1.0**?

Thanks.

Comment: did you found answer? I am new for magento and  I am looking for tuts for the same...